# How to get comment from MSVS2010 when I try and check in from CMD?

Tags: tfs

I have several projects on the go.  So I download a copy of the code to a workspace, work on that and then shelve it for my manager and others to review with comments (this is done from within the MSVS2010 IDE's Pending Changes window/tab).  Then when that is completed, I check in the changes.

Thing is, I would like not to have to load up the MSVS2010 environment every time I just have to do a check in.  It's bulky and has a lot of windows popping up that I would like to avoid.  So I would like to just execute a command line command to do the check in for me.

I tried `tf checkin /shelveset:<name-of-shelveset>` and I get this error:

```
TF204000: The Team Foundation server to which your team project is connected does not support the CheckInShelveset command.
```

Using `tf checkin <path-to-workspace>` worked but I don't have the shelveset comments.

Is there a way to get the comments populated with the shelveset comments I used last from within MSVS2010 without having to load it up?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add your `profil as owner` of shelveset, it's optional but important when shelveset can be created by lot of users

```
tf checkin /shelveset:<name-of-shelveset>;shelvesetowner
```